# Prevent changes to input values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

We're developing an angular app (using Angular 5).

Our components typically has input and output parameters defined like this:

```
export class MultipleItemPickerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() itemPickerHeaderText: string;
  @Output() multipleItemsPickerOkClick: EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() multipleItemsPickerCancelClick: EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter();
```

In the corresponding template file, it is used like this:

```
<app-multiple-item-picker itemPickerHeaderText="{{question.texts['reason']}}" (multipleItemsPickerOkClick)="multipleReasonsPickerOkClick($event)" (multipleItemsPickerCancelClick)="multipleReasonsPickerCancelClick($event)"></app-multiple-item-picker>
```

And everything works just fine.

But in the same class it is possible to set the input value to something different than the original input value.

```
removeItemClick() {
    this.itemPickerHeaderText = "something completely different";
}
```

I want to prevent any changes to the input values. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could mark the input property as `readonly`, the typescript compiler will prevent someone to update the input value inside the class from outside the constructor.

```
@Input() 
public readonly itemPickerHeaderText: string;
```

It's a little bit hacky but it should work in your case. Because the angular compiler won't complain about that it's read-only and the typescript compiler doesn't know about angular input bindings.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!